# How can I make gVim show a correct taskbar icon in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, vim, icons, gvim

I'm using gvim 7.3, and for some reason the taskbar icon shown is just the default Win32 "program" icon. I run the EXE itself.

Any idea how can I make gVim show an actual icon? I don't want to create a shortcut because I run the EXE itself from numerous apps in my system.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to happen only with the gvim executable, so what I did was to create a shortcut to gvim, then in its properties change its icon to the `vim.exe` file, then pin this shortcut to the task bar.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because you took the time to write it -- thank you very much. However, for me the problem simply stopped occuring, completely randomly. It just fixed itself one day without me doing anything, so I didn't get a chance to test your solution. At any rate, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

gVim's `guioptions` has a special element for icon: `i`. So, to have the window icon set, edit your `.gvimrc` (not sure how it's named and where it's located in Windows) adding the following line:

```
set guioptions+=i
```

Comment: This fixed it for me on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, instead of installing the program to c:\program files (x86)\vim I installed it to c:\program files\vim (it seems for some reason to look for the icon there)